# DynamoDB - Delete table without deleting replica

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Any idea on how can I delete a table without deleting the replica tables?

The exception I'm receiving is as shown below, If I delete the replica tables, the delete operation succeeds.

> Replica cannot be deleted because it has acted as a source region for new replica(s) being added to the table in the last 24 hours. (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: XXXXX; Proxy: null)`

Note: Using 2019 version of global tables, so any `UpdateGlobalTable` and its friends are unusable here!

Comment: Are you talking about breaking off a replica from a global table into its own separate table?

Comment: infact, i want to delete the stack from that region. That means the table gets destroyed as well. not to break off as a separate table.

Answer (score 1):

In principle you could use the `UpdateGlobalTable` [API-Call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateGlobalTable.html) to add or delete replicas, but there seem to be some limitations, which are among others described in the error messages:

> Replica cannot be deleted because it has acted as a source region for new replica(s) being added to the table in the last 24 hours.

I assume you've probably added replicas in the last 24 hours and the Global table seems to have chosen the replica you're trying to delete as the source to copy data into the new replica, i.e. bootstrapping for new replicas.

**I'd try again tomorrow.**

Can you do a `DescribeGlobalTable` [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeGlobalTable.html) and tell us which replica you're trying to delete - maybe that will give us more details.

Comment: I'm using 2019 version of the global table. So all the `UpdateGlobalTable` and its friends are unusable.

Comment: Ah, maybe that's something you could mention in your question ;-)